# Not able to use tensorflow and keras library in visual studio code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code, deep-learning

I am building a deep learning app, for that I need to import tensorflow and keras libraries in VSC but unfortunately, I couldn't import it though I have installed tensorflow successfully. Also I have checked the package in virtual environment(pip list), it is there. I have tried almost everything but i haven't found the solution.

**Error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Users\Rupak\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    
    
    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
    
    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using conda and pip together. It's best to not mix the to, so I would either switch to virtual environments and then try installing again, or stick with conda and install tensorflow using conda itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you had founded [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794) page, but this page seems provides some solutions to your problem. If you didn't find it, you'd better be careful about the information which the outputs provided. As it says: **See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors**